# Removing an int from a Line of String. Then, putting the int to a variable

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

```
String team1=z.nextLine(), team2;

int num1, num2;

num1 = z.Int();
team1 = z.nextLine();
team1 = team1.replaceAll("[0-9]","");

System.out.println(team1 + " " + num1);
```

I need to scan a text file with a content of "Alpha Beta Gamma 52". The String "Alpha Beta Gamma" must be placed to team1 and 52 must be placed to num1. When I use the .replaceAll, it removes the 52 that hinders me to have the integer.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, once you remove the value from the String; the value isn't in the String. How about something like this instead?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String in = "Alpha Beta Gamma 52";
  String[] arr = in.split(" ");                // split the string by space.
  String end = arr[arr.length - 1];            // get the last "word"
  boolean isNumber = true;
  for (char c : end.trim().toCharArray()) {    // check if every character is a digit.
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
      isNumber = false;                        // if not, it's not a number.
    }
  }
  Integer value = null;                        // the numeric value.
  if (isNumber) {
    value = Integer.valueOf(end.trim());
  }
  if (value != null) {
    in = in.substring(0, in.length()
        - (String.valueOf(value).length() + 1)); // get the length of the 
                                                 // numeric value (as a String).
  }
  // Display
  if (value != null) {
    System.out.printf("in = %s, value = %d", in, value);
  } else {
    System.out.println(in + " does not end in a number");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String readLine = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        String team1 = readLine.replaceAll("\\d", "");
        int team2 = Integer.parseInt(readLine.replaceAll("\\D", ""));

        System.out.println(team1); //Alpha Beta Gamma
        System.out.println(team2); //52    

}
```

Comment: for the second replace regex, I recommend using `\\D`: `replaceAll("\\D","")`. This will remove *all* non-digits.

Comment: I want to keep them, not remove them

Comment: I was talking about the second regex. There, you want to keep only the digits. `\D` matches all non-digits, so `readLine.replaceAll("\\D","");` would return a `String` that only contains digits. To extend to include a `-` sign, I'd have my regex as follows: `[^\d-]`

Answer (score 0):

Split before a number, then parse the parts:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" (?=\\d)");
String team = parts[0];
int score = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```